# Store sudo password within bash environment variables - the paranoid way

Tags: bash, security, openssl, environment-variables, sudo

I'm trying to store the sudo pw in an environment var within a bash script, using openssl encryption and two functions:

```
create_sudo_pw () {
    local pass=$( read -p "Enter sudo password (OpenSSL encrypted): " -s ; builtin echo "$REPLY" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -pbkdf2 -salt -pass pass:$rand_pass )
    echo $pass
}

sudo_with_pw () {
    builtin echo "$sudo_password" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -pbkdf2 -salt -pass pass:$rand_pass -d | sudo --stdin "$@"
}
```

Variables:

```
# creates random password for encrpyting
rand_pass=$( cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:alpha:]' | fold -w ${1:-100} | head -n1 )
# encrypted sudo password
sudo_password="$( create_sudo_pw )"
```

After that the script calls the function sudo_with_pw where necessary. The goal is to encrypt the password as good as possible and to not store it unencrypted in the ram.

Are there any toughts of how to do so even more effective?

The variables need to be in the environment, cause i did't found a way jet storing them persistent local within a function and I need them multiple times..

Ty

Comment: (1) I don't see whree you would encrypt/decrypt the password. (2) I don't see that you would store it in the environment (there is no `export` in the code you posted).

Comment: (1) not sure what you mean. could you be more precise?

Comment: *The goal is to encrypt the password as good as possible and to not store it unencrypted in the ram.*  And where is the password put when it's decrypted? Umm, RAM.  If a user needs to run a certain command with superuser privileges from a script, you need to configure `sudo` to allow **that user** to run **that command** without a password.  Concocting a homegrown scheme to try and protect passwords isn't going to work - if it worked it would already be implemented.

Comment: In your description, you said that you want to store the pwd in memory in *encrypted* form. This means that you have to encrypt it somewhere, and that you have to decrypt it when passing it to sodo. I don't see any attempt in your code, and don't know how your encryption process looks like.

Comment: Set up a proper sudorole with NOPASSWD for the command you're trying to use, instead of reinventing the wheel on password en/decryption.